# Set playback position of MIDI file in pygame

Tags: python, audio, pygame, midi

I would really like to be able to start playback from a certain place in a MIDI file using the pygame.mixer.music module, but I get the following error:

```
error: Position not implemented for music type
```

(This is with pygame 1.9.1.)

I can't see any other library that has this kind of MIDI to audio synthesis that I could use. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've pygame 1.9.1 on python 2.7.x.  I am able to simulate `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_pos'`  error.
As per documentation that comes with installed version which is at `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pygame\docs`

**1) First Choice:**
pygame version 1.9.2 onwards has `pygame.mixer.music.set_pos`  function. Hence you may want to try and upgrade pygame to 1.9.2
The official documentation on the pygame web site is for 1.9.2 which we all are referring to.
[Here is a link](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.set_pos) to official 1.9.2 pygame documentation

**2) Second Choice:**
Next, with current version you can try and use 
`pygame.mixer.music.play(loop= ?, start=? )` parameters, but that only works for MP3 and OGG.
Hence you will need to convert existing MIDI files to MP3 / OGG for this option to work.

*Best and easier option will be to upgrade pygame to 1.9.2*

**Copy/Paste from official 1.9.1 documentation**

> pygame.mixer.music.play 
>   Start the playback of the music stream
>
> pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0, start=0.0): return None
>   This will play the loaded music stream. If the music is already playing it will be restarted.
>
> The loops argument controls the number of repeats a music will play. play(5) will cause the music to played once, then repeated five times, for a total of six. If the loops is -1 then the music will repeat indefinitely.
>
> The starting position argument controls where in the music the song starts playing. The starting position is dependent on the format of music playing. MP3 and OGG use the position as time (in seconds). MOD music it is the pattern order number. Passing a startpos will raise a NotImplementedError if it cannot set the start position

Answer (score 0):

this function is not supported for midi files, it's written in the doc: "Other file formats (other than OGG, MP3 and MOD) are unsupported. Newer versions of SDL_mixer have better positioning support than earlier ones. An SDLError is raised if a particular format does not support positioning. "